# Reimaging Windows to SSD from DELL backup image

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, ssd

My friend's HDD was failing (according to SMART) in their DELL (out of warranty by about 4 months, but still less than 2 years old). I offered to replace with with a SSD since they wanted the speed boost it would bring. I'm using the built in DELL recovery image. I installed it no problem and used the DELL recovery image and recovery software (DELL DataSafe Local Backup). It imaged it correctly as it boots into Windows without a problem. However, after a reboot it says "The boot selection failed because a required device is inaccessible". AHCI looks like it was automatically applied in the BIOS, so that's not it. Am I doing something wrong or it because the backup image was from from a HDD based image?

Is it better to install windows from a stock Microsoft image?

Thanks in advance guys!

Comment: So after restore it will boot into Windows once, and that's it?

Comment: Was the Dell image for all the factory partitions or did it just restore the C partition?

Comment: Yeah, it will only boot once. The Dell image was weird, it actually partitioned my SSD into two, one for the OS (C:), one for a backup of the factory image (it took up 20GB of valuable SSD space!).

Answer (score 2):

I ended up downloading EasyBCD and seeing that my boot device was listed as unknown. I added C:\ to the entry and now it works fine. I'm not sure why the DELL image had issues creating a valid boot entry. Either way, after restoring the DELL image, turns out there is so much bloatware garbage that I'm just going to use a clean image of Windows 7. I'll create my buddy a backup image after installing all the required drivers, etc.